# Connecting three parallel LED strips to the same power supply

Tags: power-supply, led, led-strip

I have got a shelf like the sketch. Behind it, there's a power outlet. I want to connect three LED strips as well as a power strip to it. Also, since there's not much space behind the shelf, I have to use a slim plug, like the following:

[image]

There are three holes on the back of the shelf, through which the wires can go to connect to the strips. How can I connect the strips and the power strip to the same outlet, while the power strip needs 220v and the strips require less voltage. What kind of connections and adapters do I need to setup this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you know how to splice wires? that's going to be the cheapest and arguably best way; use one beefy ac-dc converter (aka transformer, charger, adapter) and splice in additional male DC jacks (or whatever connector your strips use). They also sell DC jack splitters, but I find the wiring skimpy in those, not good for higher power lighting, but might be adequate for your install. Or you can use 3 small adapters, simple and effective but bulky.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.